# Typescript: Discriminating unions without explicitly creating the discriminant?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, data-transform

I want to pass typed data from a database into a generic transformer function. It seems like the best way to accomplish this in Typescript is via a discriminating union. But, this requires a discriminant property. Is there a way to auto-generate the discriminant? Or, is there a way to write a generic transformer function using something other than a discriminated union? I'm open to other solutions besides the kind I'm suggesting below.

```js
type DB1 = {
  id: string
  one: string
}

type DB2 = {
  id: string
  two: string
}

type One = {
  id: number
  one: string
}

type Two = {
  id: number
  two: string
}

function transformer(x: DB1): One
function transformer(x: DB2): Two
function transformer(x: DB1 | DB2): One | Two {
  switch (x.kind) { // There is no x.kind!
    case 'DB1': return db1ToOne(x)
    case 'DB2': return db2ToTwo(x)
  }
}
```

The challenge is easily discriminating between DB1 and DB2. Since they come from the database library directly, I do not manually instantiate the types myself, and so I do not have an opportunity "on creation" of the objects to manually include a discriminant property. I also don't really like the idea of "hacking" into DB1 and DB2 and tacking on a discriminant just before I pass it to the transformer.

Is there a way to discriminate between these types so that the transformer works the way I want it to?

(Also, since this solution is supposed to scale to many types, don't assume there is anything else besides a potential discriminant property which can otherwise differentiate between types.)

Comment: How would you be able to tell the difference between two different types if they don't have a discriminant property? In this scenario (`DB1` and `DB2`), you could just say `x` is `DB1` and not a `DB2` if `'one' in x`. However, how do you expect this to work for more complicated types? Are you after something that automatically generates code that differentiates between two types and adds the appropriate discriminant property?

Comment: Yes @cherryblossom , that is essentially what I'm looking for. I also think that, more broadly, there are occasions where one would not want to modify the sub-types of a union-type, but still desire to differentiate between them in someway. External discriminants, auto-generated internal discriminants, etc. Curious if the community has strategies for this situation.